# Rails 6 ActionMailer params is nil in preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I get this error after visit `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/confirm_email`:

```rb
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
@user = params[:user]
```

My code:

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_email
    @user = params[:user]
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.with(user: User.first).confirm_email
  end
end
```

If I change code to this:

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.confirm_email(User.last)
  end
end
```

I receive this:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

I cant understand, what I'm doing wrong?

My rails version is 6.0.2.1

**Update:**

First case worked from console, but not worked from browser preview. Second case not worked from console.

Comment: It is pretty strange as both should work. Have you set a breakpoint inside of `UserMailerPreview#confirm_email` to ensure that its being run?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Preview class should be in the `spec` folder, not in the `app`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this same problem by removing the Letter Opener gem from my project. Letter Opener has similar functionality to the now built-in ActionMailer previews.